# Facebook video upload from iPhone using both Social.framework and FB SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, file-upload, facebook-ios-sdk

We've got a problem with our ios app. THe thing is, that uploading through ios doesn't seem to work like expected. The real problem here, is that we are able to upload from some accounts, while we can't upload from others (although, we could do that before). The bug reproduction steps are following:
- user launches our app;
- user logs into facebook and gives the necessary permissions for the app to work;
- user uploads the video to facebook;
- facebook responds with upload success;
- then the message comes up on the facebook, that video couldn't be processed.

This same video was successfully uploaded from other accounts.

THe most weird thing, is that the videos we've successfully uploaded disappear from the facebook page after some time.

So, what we are basically thinking of, is that FB has some spam protection limitations for a user from mobile devices.

So, what I'm, asking, is if anyone had such issues as well?

P.S. Code for sending stuff to FB is pretty basic:

```
- (void)uploadVideoToFacebookFromFileURL:(NSURL *)url parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters {
SLRequest *uploadRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                        URL:[NSURL URLWithString:kFBVideoURLString]
                                                 parameters:parameters];

NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:NULL];

[uploadRequest addMultipartData:videoData
                       withName:@"source"
                           type:@"video/x-m4v"
                       filename:[url absoluteString]];

uploadRequest.account = self.socialAccount;

IDPLoadingView *loadingView = [IDPLoadingView loadingViewInView:self.view];
[uploadRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[loadingView removeFromSuperview];});
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self showErrorSending];});
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self showResult];});
    }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must make 2 different requests.. first is for reading permissions and after post permissions for first-use logged to Facebook  users

```
NSArray * p = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil];

NSDictionary * dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"fb_app_id",ACFacebookAppIdKey,p,ACFacebookPermissionsKey,ACFacebookAudienceEveryone,ACFacebookAudienceKey, nil];



    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"fb_app_id",
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_actions", ],
                              @"ACFacebookAudienceKey": ACFacebookAudienceFriends,
                              };
    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore
                                          accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:dict completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"blablalba");
      //do nothing here.

    }];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
 //code for upload here
}];
```

Hope it helps.